# how to make a login by using the Pin

Tags: python

```
status_login = False
use_atm = "y"

 data =[{"norek":932012042,
                "pin":123,
                "name":"grizly",
                "bank":"BCA",
                "balance":5000000},
                {"norek":932012052,
                "pin":1234,
                "name":"Basuki Pepeh",
                "bank":"BRI",
                "balance":4000000},
                {"norek":932012099,
                "pin":1235,
                "name":"Bambang Gentolet",
                "bank":"Mandiri",
                "balance":3500000}]
def cek_login(p):
    for login in data:
        if login['pin'] == p:
            return login
    return False  

while use_atm == "y":
    while status_login == False:
        print("Welcome to ATM")
        print("insert your pin")
        pin = input("PIN : ")
        if cek_login(pin) != False:
            print("welcome "+cek_login(pin)['name'])
            status_login = True
        else:
            print("")
            print("Ops Your PIN is wrong")
            print("")
            print("")
```

I want to make a login using a pin but why the result is always wrong, what is wrong with the code above

Welcome to ATM
insert your pin
PIN : 123

Ops Your PIN is wrong

Comment: `pin` in your data is an integer.  `pin` in your input is a `str`.  They will never compare equal.  Learn to use a source debugger to find the logic problem.

Answer (score 0):

The pin in your data is int.

input is str.

`str` is not equal to `int`.

```
pin = int(input("PIN : "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is failing in `cek_login`, so print the values using `repr()` and see why they don't compare.  Note that `repr()` gives a debugging representation of the data so it is easier to spot differences:

```
def cek_login(p):
    for login in data:
        print(repr(long['pin']),repr(p))   # see why they don't compare
        if login['pin'] == p:
            return login
    return False
```

You will see:

```
Welcome to ATM
insert your pin 123
123 '123'                # note integer versus string (quoted).
1234 '123'
1235 '123'
```

Convert the input to an integer to fix the problem.

```
pin = int(input("PIN : "))
```

You'll also find that you will enter an infinite loop after getting the pin correct, because `use_atm` never changes.

Learn to use a source debugger so you don't have to litter your code with print statements.

Answer (score -2):

There were a couple bugs here, and some other people already pointed them out:

1. `cek_login(p)` uses `data`, which is a list of dictionaries, so you need to first access the dictionary in the list by index (`[0]`, `[1]`, ...), and THEN access the dictionary element with bracket notation like `['pin']`
2. `data[0]['pin']` is an `int`, whereas the result of `input()` is a `str`, so you need to CONVERT the `str` to an `int` with `int(my_str_input)`
3. Similar to point 1, the print statement under the while loop which prints the user's name needs to first access the index in the list (`data`) before accessing the dictionary value (`[name]`)

Try this:

```
status_login = False
use_atm = "y"

data =[{"norek":932012042,
                "pin":123,
                "name":"grizly",
                "bank":"BCA",
                "balance":5000000},
                {"norek":932012052,
                "pin":1234,
                "name":"Basuki Pepeh",
                "bank":"BRI",
                "balance":4000000},
                {"norek":932012099,
                "pin":1235,
                "name":"Bambang Gentolet",
                "bank":"Mandiri",
                "balance":3500000}]
def cek_login(p):
    print(int(p))
    print(data[0]['pin'])
    if data[0]['pin'] == int(p):
        return True
    return False  

while use_atm == "y":
    while status_login == False:
        print("Welcome to ATM")
        print("insert your pin")
        pin = input("PIN : ")
        if cek_login(pin) != False:
            print("welcome "+ data[0]['name'])
            status_login = True
            use_atm = "n"
        else:
            print("")
            print("Ops Your PIN is wrong")
            print("")
            print("")
```

Comment: cek_login is a function. That isnt the problem. @Mark Tolonen has it correct. He is comparing a str to an int which will never succeed.

Comment: sorry, modified the answer, try the updated one now :)

Comment: updated again, please check now! running the code should work, tested in python3

Comment: there were addditional bugs in `cek_login(p)` as well as the `print` statement. Fixed the print statement to `print("welcome "+ data[0]['name'])`

Comment: Code only answers are not useful.  Explain the problem and the solution.

Comment: Updated again! Should I include anything else?

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the welcome print, other than repetitively calling `cek_login`.  Your solution always prints the name of the first data name, and not the one corresponding to the pin.